# Non rendered p:dataTable ends up in pe:exporter PDF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have 2 dataTables:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl1" var="prop1" value="#{bean.prop1}" rendered="#{bean.listP1.size() != 0}">
// ...
</p:dataTable>
```

and

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl2" var="prop2" value="#{bean.prop2}" rendered="#{bean.listP2.size() != 0}">
// ...
</p:dataTable>
```

On XHTML page, after some action, I got the correct result depending on the size of both `listP1` and `listP2`.

My problem is after clicking on **export button**

```
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/download.png" style="width : 35px; height:35px"/>
    <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="tbl1, tbl2" fileName="SurveyResults"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I got wrong result : I got the two tables instead of one because one of them is with `size = 0`

Have you please any idea about solving that?

Comment: Make your exporter `target` attribute an EL expression to only target the rendered tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior to version 8, the `pe:exporter` does not care whether the data tables you provide are rendered or not, see https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/757

If you are not on version 8 yet, you can use EL to create a dynamic value for the `target` attribute though. For example:

```
<pe:exporter type="pdf"
             target="#{empty bean.listP1 ? '' : 'tbl1'}#{empty bean.listP1 or empty bean.listP2 ? '' : ','}#{empty bean.listP2 ? '' : 'tbl2'}"
             fileName="SurveyResults"/>
```

As these expressions are a bit hairy, you might want to create a method in your bean which creates a target string and do:

```
<pe:exporter type="pdf"
             target="#{bean.exporterTargets}"
             fileName="SurveyResults"/>
```

And in your bean for example:

```
public String getExporterTargets() {
   return Stream.of(listP1.isEmpty() ? null : "tbl1",
                    listP2.isEmpty() ? null : "tbl2")
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
}
```

Comment: @melloware should we add a rendered check in the exporter?

Comment: Big thanks @JasperDeVries. It workd as well now, you save my day.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/757

Comment: OMG, Thanks a lot Sir for your kindness

Comment: Yes I think we should!